# Find the area of the smallest tangential trapezoid?

Tags: geometry

So, how do I find the area of the smallest trapeziod with inscribed circle? The only thing I know is the circle radius, which is $8$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Consider the two parallel sides.  They must be tangent to the circle at opposite ends of a diameter.  If you cut the diagram along that diameter, you should be able to convince yourself that the figure is symmetric-if you minimize the area to the left of the diameter, the shape on the right will be the mirror image.  Let the length of half one parallel side be $x$.  Use geometry to find the length of half the other parallel side as a function of $x$, call it $y$.  As the area of the trapezoid is $8(x+y)$, you want to minimize $x+y$, so take the derivative with respect to $x$, set to zero, solve.

Added:  it isn't as easy as I thought.  See the diagram below.  If you draw the line from the center to the intersection  of the two $x$ segments, you find $x=8 \tan \frac t2$ and $y=8\tan (\frac 12(\pi-t))$  so you can take $\frac {d(x+y)}{dt}$ and set it to zero.  Symmetry should lead you to guess you want $t=\frac \pi2$

[image]

Comment: Since I'm not a native English, I ask for a little help. Can you please write what's the derivative of x+y with respect to x, what do you mean by that?

Comment: You might find, for example, that $y=\frac 4x$.  Then $x+y=x+\frac 4x$ and $\frac d{dx}(x+y)=1-\frac 4{x^2}$

Comment: One last question :D I have no idea how to find y. Please help me there!

Comment: Note that the other side of the trapezoid is tangent to the circle.  From each corner of the trapezoid you have two tangents to the circle.  Do you know a theorem about the two tangents to a circle from the same point?

Comment: They are equal?

Comment: That is correct. Can you use that to find $y(x)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15016/discussion-between-a6tech-and-ross-millikan).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to use that theorem in this case.